# Show the title from a Tableau Dashboard Object when exporting underlying data to Excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, export, title, tableau-api

How do I show the title from a Tableau Dashboard Object when exporting the underlying data from it to Excel?

Table on Dashboard in Tableau, with `Population by ZCTA5` Title and Sheet Name:

[image: Table on Dashboard in Tableau, with Title and Sheet Name]

Crosstab exported to excel, no `Population by ZCTA5` Title or Sheet Name from Tableau :-/

[image: Crosstab exported to excel, no Title or Sheet Name from Tableau]

How do I show the `Population by ZCTA5` Title in the exported Excel sheet?  I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer? You can't.

Tableau is generally the "end game" when it comes to data analysis, so while the tool can do exporting, we tend to focus our time on other (arguably) higher-value asks that customers have -- not a good thing in your case.

You'll find that Tableau's export capabilities are (generally) "all about the data", not the titles / images / whatever that wrap the data. We don't attempt to export a full-fidelity version of a dashboard to Excel as there's no reason to.

Not the answer that you're looking for, but hopefully it'll save you some time. Sorry.